# ScrollLeft() not working with Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/DyfGp/2/ - where an outer box contains an inner box that extends out of the viewport. This forces a horizontal scroll bar to appear.

A "Get Left 
Scroll" button reads the current left scroll and a "Set Left Scroll to 20" button sets the left scroll to 20.  This all works as I would expect on Chrome and Safari: Initially selecting Get Left Scroll returns 0 because nothing is missing off the left end. If I maually move the scroll bar some, selecting Get Left Scroll returns the amount I've scrolled, because now this amount is missing off the left end.  If is select "Set Left Scroll to 20"  the scroll moves 20 and 20px are now missing off the left end.  Excellent!

The problem is that none of this works in Firefox. In Firefox all the scroll reads come back as 0 and writing a scroll doesn't seem to do anything.  Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks

```
 $('#getScroll').click(function() {

        var bodyscroll = $('body').scrollLeft();
        $('#scroll').html("left scroll is " + bodyscroll);

    });

    $('#setScroll').click(function() {
        $('body').scrollLeft(20);
        var bodyscroll = $('body').scrollLeft();
        $('#scroll').html("left scroll is " + bodyscroll);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `scrollLeft` on the `window` not the `body`.

```
var windowscroll = $(window).scrollLeft();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DyfGp/5/

Comment: Yes!  window seems to make everyone happy: Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.  Thanks