# jQuery not working in Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, safari

I'm currently using the following jquery (along with the mousewheel plugin) to allow for vertical and horizontal scrolling on the same web page (diagram also shown below)

```
scrollVert();
var scrollLeft=0;

function scrollVert() {
  $('html, body, *').off('mousewheel').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollTop -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
        scrollHoriz();
    }, 0)

  });
}
function scrollHoriz() {
  $('html, body, *').off('mousewheel').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollLeft=this.scrollLeft
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (scrollLeft == 0) scrollVert();
    }, 0)
  });
}
```

[image]

The code works correctly in Chrome but in Firefox and Safari it doesn't seem to be working. With Firefox it reaches the bottom of the page and doesn't scroll horizontally with the mousewheel. In Safari, it scrolls horizotnally at the bottom but doesn't retrun to vertical scrolling.

Comment: Please refer following stack overflow link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731387/scrollleft-not-working-with-firefox[Click here]

Comment: Hi @R.Patel I've tried that already and it doesn't seem to work with my code